# Swift - Import my swift class

Tags: xcode, swift, class, import

This question is asked several times, but I can't find the right solution for my problem. I'm trying to import my `Player.swift` class in my `MainScene.swift` (I've used Cocos2D - SpriteBuilder to setup the project; Now using Xcode).

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I've tried to use `import Player;` and `import Player.swift;`, but when I tried I got this error: **No such module 'Player.swift'**

How do I import it correctly?

Thanks!

By the way, I'm a beginner in Swift, so don't expect that I know all of the terms

Comment: You don't need to import anything. Just go right ahead and use the Player class.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly import files in Swift as they are globally available through the project. If you want to access the methods or properties of `Player class`, you can directly make object of Player class in `MainScene.Swift` file and can access to it.
`e.g var objPlayer = Player()`

Comment: FYI i had created a folder and the auto linking did not work.  i had to move them into a group and then it worked.

Comment: I tested this by creating a project where one `.swift` file has `import UIkit` and another does not.  Sure enough, Xcode threw errors and I thought aha! this answer is wrong.  But then I remembered that UIKit is an Objective C framework, not a Swift Framework.

Answer (score 31):

**There is no need to import swift classes to use in other swift classes.
They are available to use automatically.**

**In Swift you can only import module, e.g. any framework like UIKit, MapKit as below. You cannot import swift classes.**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
```

Just make sure its selected to use in target in which your are trying to use.

**Check below images for more idea.**

In this image my `HomeViewController.swift` is selected to use in `AutolayoutDemo` module.
[image]

In below image I have unchecked `AutolayoutDemo` module for the class `DetailsViewController.swift`.[image]

So now onwards when I will try to use the `DetailsViewController` compiler will give me error as below image in `HomeViewController`.
[image]

Comment: Note that you _can_ import a single class, if you really want to - see Nick Fox's answer.

Comment: [This article](https://paigeshin1991.medium.com/learn-swift-import-statements-usages-that-junior-developers-don-t-know-about-b42234036c77) describes how you can import swift class, struct, func, var, enum etc.

Answer (score 15):

When it comes to Swift imports, there are two cases:

**1) The type to import is in the module**

In this case, no import statement is needed. As long as the type is not `private` or `fileprivate`, you can directly access it.

**2) The type to import is outside of the module**

You can import an entire module using:

```
import ModuleName
```

If you only want to import a specific type or function from the module, you can do this using the following format:

```
import kindOfThing ModuleName.Type
```

where kindOfThing is `class`/`struct`/`func`/etc...

A much deeper exploration of this can be found on NSHipster [here](https://nshipster.com/import/).

Comment: this second example was very helpful, but the syntax threw me a little and I had to follow the link to NSHipster (thank you).  I'd suggest: `import kindOfThing ModuleName.NameOfThing`

Answer (score 3):

Check if the class is added to your iOS target in right Pane or not .

Comment: this work for Flutter